# Study the character of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{1}{n^{2z}}\right|^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Discuss the character of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{1}{n^{2z}}\right|^2$$

where $z\in \mathbb C$ and $|z|=\frac{1}{4}$.

Any suggestions please?

Thank you very much

Comment: $$\underset{n\geq1}{\sum}\left|\frac{1}{n^{2z}}\right|^{2}=\underset{n\geq1}{ \sum}\frac{1}{n^{4\Re\left(z\right)}}$$ where $\Re\left(z\right)$ is the real part of $z$. So the series converge if $\Re\left(z\right)>1/4$. But you can't understand it from $\left|z\right|=\frac{1}{4}.$

Comment: ... but $\Re z=|z| \cos\theta$?

Comment: I didn't know this identity. If it is true, then $4\Re\left(z\right)=\cos\theta\leq1$ so the series diverges.

Comment: And now, +200 bounty for the comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\left|n^{-2z}\right|^2=\left|n^{-2\Re (z)-2 i \Im (z)}\right|^2=\left(n^{-2 \Re(z)}\right)^2=n^{-4\Re(z)}
$$
for $n\ge 1$, so the sum is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-4\Re(z)}=\zeta\left(4\Re(z)\right),
$$
with convergence only for $4\Re(z) > 1$.  If we are given that $\left|z\right|=1/4$, clearly $\Re(z) \le 1/4$, and so the series diverges on the specified circle in the complex plane.

Comment: The k in the formula $\lvert n^z\rvert = n^{\operatorname{Re} z}\cdot \exp(2\pi k\operatorname{Im} z)$ involved in convergence/divergence?

Comment: I don't believe that formula is correct… $\left| n^z \right|=\sqrt{n^{z} n^{\bar{z}}}=\sqrt{n^{x+iy} n^{x-iy}}=\sqrt{n^{2x}}=n^x$, where $x=\Re(z)$.  There's no dependence on $\Im(z)$ at all.

Comment: Oh, I see your point.  Since $n^z$ is technically multivalued for complex $z$, you could consider other branches beyond the principal branch.